# Elaborating items in a big list using the ExecutorService

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, executorservice

I have a huge collection of items and I need to execute some operations on each item without changing them.

Currently all I've tried is using an ExecutorService and a fixed size pool, but it elaborates a certain number of items and then stops, the code looks like this:

```kotlin
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30)
val cursor = ....
var current = 0

while (cursor.moveToNext()) {  //This is a actually a cursor rather than a list
    val worker = Runnable {
        //elaborate data in cursor

        //print somewhere the current item count
        //current++
    }

    pool.submit(worker)
}
```

This does seem to elaborate a few items, 40 on my device, and then stop.
Is there a limit on how many threads the submit can queue? Is there a better way of doing this? I have lots of data, around 37k entries on my current device

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do not create a new Runnable to be executed for each item, this is the wasting of resources. Instead of that, put all items into a thread-safe queue and submit N tasks each of which, in a loop, pools/takes the next item from the queue and processes it. This is the Work Queue pattern:

```
    final int numOfWorkers = 30;

    final BlockingQueue items = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1000);

    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfWorkers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfWorkers; i++) {
        pool.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final Object item = items.take();

                    // process the item
                    // ...
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { // we are here because of
                    // pool.shutdownNow() is called
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) { // an error while processing the item
                    e.printStackTrace(); // use some logging?
                } finally {
                    if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        // notify about an item has been processed/queue changed
                        synchronized (items) {
                            items.notify();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    val cursor = ....

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {  //This is a actually a cursor rather than a list
        items.put(cursor.item); // put next item to the queue
    }

    // wait until the queue is empty/all items have been processed
    synchronized(items) {
        while (!items.isEmpty()) {
            items.wait();
        }
    }

    pool.shutdownNow(); // now interrupt all ExecutorService's threads
```

And use something like AtomicXXX or LongAdder to make a counter in the multithreaded environment.